# Что значит запись

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Что значит сия конструкция?

```
$a = <<<DTD
//some string
DTD;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это один из способов записи строковых значений - [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)